# How to hide an error message when error is fixed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validate plugin and would like to show all errors at one place. I have html like below:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <p class="pull-left hide" id="register-result"></p>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
$("#company").validate({
  errorClass: "error",
  errorElement: "div",
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $("#register-result").html(error);
    $("#register-result").show();
  },
...
```

It works almost as expected - the error message is displayed where needed. But when user fixed the error, error message is still displayed. How can I change it?

Comment: Is there a success returned? I'm only seeing error, not success.

Comment: @BrianNoah, it wasn't defined.. I've added it and now it works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#company").validate({
    errorClass: "error",
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $("#register-result").html(error);
        $("#register-result").show();
    },
    success: function() {
        $("#register-result").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include a success return.

```
success: function () {
    $('#register-result').fadeOut();
}
```